# How to specify how many messages to pull on pubsub using Go?

Tags: go, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm following this article on how to pull messages from a subscription: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull.

Apparently I can pull up to 1,000 messages, but what do I have to do if I want to pull only 2 messages for example? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you can specify the number of msgs in [synchronous pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#go_6). tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous pull supports the requirement of retrieving the precise number of messages by the client.

For example follow the below code:

```
func pullMsgsSync(w io.Writer, projectID, subID string) error {
        // projectID := "my-project-id"
        // subID := "my-sub"
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("pubsub.NewClient: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        sub := client.Subscription(subID)
        sub.ReceiveSettings.Synchronous = true
        sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxOutstandingMessages = 2
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 10*time.Second)
        defer cancel()

        var received int32
        err = sub.Receive(ctx, func(_ context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "Got message: %q\n", string(msg.Data))
                atomic.AddInt32(&received, 1)
                msg.Ack()
        })
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("sub.Receive: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Received %d messages\n", received)

        return nil
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sakshi! How's it going? So the secret here is the MaxOutstandingMessages, right? I'll test this option in my application and be right back!